How do I await a JsObject in dart?
I am JavaScript to connect to Microsoft SignalR server, as I did not find any dart packages that support signalR client in Flutter Web. I included https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/microsoft-signalr/8.0.7/signalr.min.js" in my head tag. Then I initialize the connection using
js.JsObject connection
connection= js.JsObject(js.context['signalR']['HubConnectionBuilder'])
    .callMethod('withUrl', [
  url,
]).callMethod('build');

final completer = Completer<void>();
connection.callMethod('start').callMethod('then', [
  () {
    completer.complete();
  },
  (error) {
    completer.completeError(error);
  }
]);

The error occurs on the following line of code
final message = JSPromise<JSAny>(await connection.callMethod(
    'invoke', [
  'Send',
  message,"
]));

Error:

TypeError: Instance of 'JsObject': type 'JsObject' is not a subtype of type 'JavaScriptFunction'

The JSPromise is currently not awaiting the result from my server. How can I ensure that JSPromise await a result from my server?

What does the error message say?

TypeError: Instance of 'JsObject': type 'JsObject' is not a subtype of type 'JavaScriptFunction'

check: https://www.perplexity.ai/search/0-i-am-javascript-to-connect-t-_QVVcWPOSk6TRIzaerzfIw
